# How to add div to span inside this table row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table row as such:

```
        <tr class="song-row song-row-selected" data-id="1">
                <td data-col="title">
                    <span class="song-content">
                        <img src="img/cover3.jpg" />
                        Song Title
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td>3:37</td>
                <td>song artist</td>
                <td>song album</td>
                <td>23</td>
            </tr>
```

I want to add a div to indicate that the song is paused (surrounded by *):

```
        <tr class="song-row song-row-selected" data-id="1">
                <td data-col="title">
                    <span class="song-content">
                        <img src="img/cover3.jpg" />
                        Song Title
                        *<div class="song-indicator loading"></div>*
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td>3:37</td>
                <td>song artist</td>
                <td>song album</td>
                <td>23</td>
            </tr>
```

I was hoping to use JQuery. So far I have:

```
function displayPause() {
    $('tr.song-row.song-row-selected:first').each(function() {
        $(this).siblings('td span.song-content').add('<div class="song-indicator paused"></div>');
    });
}
```

Needless to say, it doesn't add the div. Also, I would like a function for me to easily remove the div from the span. Does anyone know where to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried .append('*<div....</div>*'); instead of add?

Answer (score 3):

[append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) is what you want:

```
$(this).find('td span.song-content')
       .append('<div class="song-indicator paused"></div>');
```

This will ... *append* the div to the end of your span.

Also, as tymeJV says, your td is not a sibling of your `tr`; it's a child.  Use either children, or find to grab it.

And to remove it, you'd use `remove`.  If I understand your app correctly, it should be something like this:

```
$('tr.song-row.song-row-selected:first')
        .find("div.song-indicator.paused").remove();
```

Comment: Is the `td` a sibling of that `tr`? I thought it would be `children`

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `append` as well as `children`, not `siblings`

```
$(this).children('td span.song-content').append('<div class="song-indicator paused"></div><input type="button" class="removeDiv" value="Remove"/>');
```

I also added a button right next to your div, clicking this will remove that div with this code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".removeDir", function() {
    $(this).prev(".song-indicator").remove();
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here a litte sample on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9gnL3/)

```
$("tr.song-row-selected:first td span.song-content").append("*<div class='song-indicator loading'></div>*");
```